# how to choose a threshold for Jiang-Conrath Similarity?

Tags: semantics, computational-linguistics, wordnet, word-sense-disambiguation

I want to compare two sets of keywords. After searching I understood that  `Jiang-Conrath` Similarity is closer correlating with human judgement. I read this definition:

> Jiang-Conrath Similarity Return a score denoting how similar two word senses are, based on the Information Content (IC) of the Least Common Subsumer (most specific ancestor node) and that of the two input Synsets. The relationship is given by the equation 1 / (IC(s1) + IC(s2) - 2 * IC(lcs)).

my question is that how I can choose a threshold to say that two words are simililar with `Jiang-Conrath` measurement. For example, similarity of cat and dog is only 0.4 with `Brown-ic`.

Comment: I suggest some experimentation; try some word pairs you consider more or less similar and compute the JC similarity for them and compare with your judgements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the result you can find out there would be the experimentation of someone else. So my suggestion is **make your own experimentation**: build your own classifier.

## A good and simple idea

- collect as many classified data as you can
- choose the *similarity* as a `feature` and peek the `labels` as *similar* and *non-similar*

And, assuming the data is linearly separable, find the farthest value from the two labelled sets using `SVM` (Support Vector Machine) with a `linear kernel`.